# What to choose for data share in same wifi network: Multipeer, Bonjour, Socket connection

Tags: ios, iphone, bonjour, multipeer-connectivity, gcdasyncsocket

I am working on data share over same wifi two/more iOS devices.I have successfully implemented it using multipeer networking and explored it from videos documents.I am just looking on apple Dev for difference between Bonjour vs Multipeer Networking. Is there some one in group who have worked on both and can share me his experience with what to choose.
**My requirement:
Connect two/more iOS device in Same Wifi Network**

Automatic Discovering and Connectivity.

Data Size Can be 1 KB to 1 GB.(working on it with MC).

Resume data share when disconnect and connect(looking for it with MC).

Which is more reliable?

What will YOU choose?
I am also looking at GCDAsyncSocket(Don't know i m on right direction).

So please share your experience.
Thanks.

Comment: its looking like a deep blue sea, please point me in right direction.I have tried using multipeer connectivity acheived much by using MCBrowserController as well as programmatic search . And looking now with bonjour.

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation says:

> The Multipeer Connectivity Framework provides a layer on top of Bonjour that lets you communicate with apps running on nearby devices (over infrastructure Wi-Fi, peer-to-peer Wi-Fi, and either Bluetooth (for iOS) or Ethernet (for OS X) without having to write lots of networking code specific to your app.